# Local Declaration Hides Instance Variable - tableView Not Synthesized

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have read about using underscores to fix compiler warnings that say "Local declaration hides instance variable," but I have not been able to implement a fix. The solutions I have read about say to use an underscore in my .h file, and the @synthesize part of in my .m file. However, I do not synthesize my tableView. Please see my header file below:

**.h File**

```
@interface ListViewController : GAITrackedViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, 
UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {

IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

}
```

**.m File**

```
//SYNTHESIZE
@synthesize listItems, filteredListItems, savedSearchTerm, savedScopeButtonIndex, 
searchWasActive, mapView, loadingImageView, loadingActivity;



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

 //FIRST WARNING for tableView HERE

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
    return [self.filteredListItems count];
    }
    else{
        return [self.listItems count];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    //SECOND WARNING for tableView HERE

    [tableView setRowHeight: 60.00];
    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

You have an outlet/property named tableView and your delegate method also contains tableView.

So you need to change either of them. Typically you go to change the argument names of delegate and datasource as

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
```

Answer (score 3):

Change :

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

To :

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
```

Make the same required changes in your .m file also. This warning is coming because in below delegate method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

There is a reference of `UITableView` with name `tableView` and you have given the same name. Scope of this variable is function level where as scope of your variable declare in .h is class level.

Comment: Changing outlet names may lead to you in some sort of trouble, as if you were referring it form some other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use same name : IBOutlet UITableView *tableView; use tableview or table_View

Answer (score 0):

I do also spent lot of time on this issue. Finally I could solve this problem.
The thing is we should take care of outlets which are created by us. If you change outlets names then you must connect them properly after change.In my case after lot of struggle I could finish this issue hope it will help others....
 For example if You have an outlet/property named tableView and your delegate method also contains tableView.

So you need to change either of them. Typically you go to change the argument names of delegate and datasource as
Change :

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

To :

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
```

For more information visit this link->[Local Declaration Hides Instance Variable - tableView Not Synthesized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171697/local-declaration-hides-instance-variable-tableview-not-synthesized)